# Jquery: how to create a search box

Tags: jquery, search

Hi, I need to create a custom search box (like if i press Command + F or Ctrl + F) in jQuery. Is there some plugin or some function to do this?

I've tried with the selector `:contains` but it doesn't work as expected. Thank you!

Comment: This is not a plugin or function, like you asked, hence the comment. But have you tried handling something like a keydown event?

Comment: which part is giving you trouble: popping up a search window, or searching the contents of the page? Are you just searching text nodes or the actual markup? And why duplicate browser functionality?

Comment: actually i'm trying to handle a keiup event...and i have problems when i try to search the element in the page!
i must duplicate a browser functionality because my customer press for it! (i'm contrary of this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at some of the bookmarklet versions written for mobile browsers (iPhone) which lack this functionality.

http://www.tipb.com/2007/07/31/bookmarklet-favelet-smorgasbord/

Comment: this seems very interesting! tomorrow i'll try it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:
[js-hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/wiki/about)

Comment: unfortunately this plugin doesn't help me!

Comment: Maybe you are talking about something like an autocomplete ? the most complete autocomplete i know is the yahoo,   http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/autocomplete/

Comment: no neither this! i must duplicate the "find" browser functionality with jqeury! it's a stupid thing but i have to do it!

Answer (score 0):

All you've got to do is listen to `keypress` on the document:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 70 && e.ctrlKey)
    { 
        $('#search').focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AS6A3/embedded/result/

Comment: when i write something in an input field it must search automatically in my page! without press any other key!